# Selenium python do test every 10 seconds

Tags: python, testing, selenium, automation

I am using selenium (python) testing and I need to test my application automatically every 10 seconds.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you actually need to test?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
import threading
import logging

def print_timer(count):
    if count:
        t = threading.Timer(10.0, print_timer,args=[count-1])
        t.start()
    logger.info("Begin print_timer".format(c=count))
    time.sleep(15)
    logger.info("End print_timer".format(c=count))

def using_timer():
    t = threading.Timer(0.0, print_timer,args=[3])
    t.start()

if __name__=='__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(threadName)s: %(asctime)s: %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%H:%M:%S')    
    using_timer()
```

yields

```
Thread-1: 06:46:18: Begin print_timer  --
                                         | 10 seconds
Thread-2: 06:46:28: Begin print_timer  --
Thread-1: 06:46:33: End print_timer      | 10 seconds
Thread-3: 06:46:38: Begin print_timer  --
Thread-2: 06:46:43: End print_timer      | 10 seconds
Thread-4: 06:46:48: Begin print_timer  --
Thread-3: 06:46:53: End print_timer
Thread-4: 06:47:03: End print_timer
```

Note that this will spawn a new thread ever 10 seconds. Be sure to provide some way for the thread-spawning to cease before the number of threads becomes intolerable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what resources do you have.
To run some script automatically, you should take a look at cron program

The best thing you can do is use Jenkins CI which is a tool for automatic builds

I use it for automatic tests - I build the application and run the tests, it provides lots of additional tools like graphs, detecting regressions etc.

EDIT: if you want to test every 10 seconds, then I suppose that your application is pretty small, so Jenkins is not needed, I'd take a look at cron

Comment: I agree - cron seems to be the correct tool here. There is some overhead from starting the browser and running the tests, so maybe 10 seconds is not really doable, though, unless the tests are VERY fast.

Answer (score 0):

I know that maybe it's not the best solution but if you want do something easy and fast:

```
import time

def my_function():#my function
    do_something
    .......

try:
    while True:
        my_function()#call my function
        time.sleep(10)#wait 10 second
except KeyboardInterrupt:#execute the while loop until you don't press CRTL+C, when you press it the execution is going to stop after 10 sec
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test your application automatically every 10 seconds on your Windows machine automatically and remind you about something, or even automatically send emails? Use the “[Task Scheduler](http://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/)” included with Windows – its interface can be a bit intimidating, but it’s easy to use.

The Task Scheduler has a wide variety of uses – anything you want your computer to do automatically, you can configure here. For example, you could use the task scheduler to automatically wake your computer at a specific time.