# Cron automated tests with python

Tags: python, automation, cron

How can I run my "Hello word" script in python every 10 seconds?

I know thats stupid question, because there are a lot of answers returned by google.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what have you tried? this is not a stupid question if you checked some of the google search answers or refine what is the specific things important to you to achieve. since you don't specify any of this you are getting all the downvotes

Comment: I answered you, yet I am curious: why did you asked this question if you already found "a lot of answers using google"? What did you expected to get from us more than from google? (honest question!)

Comment: i found a lot of useless answers on google so i try this ..

Comment: "Proposed to close because of 'too localized'"? C'mon, cut the kid some slack! (besides: scheduling a task is not exactly a 'rarely performed' operation) :o

Comment: Were the answers here not helpful? Becasue that's nearly the same question, asked by you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267100/selenium-python-do-test-every-10-seconds

Answer (score 2):

To schedule every 10 seconds, a simple system cron job won't be enough because the precision is on the minute.

Yet, you can use the [Advanced Python Scheduler cron-like scheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/cronschedule.html) to do it.

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

def job_function():
    print "Hello World"

# Schedules job_function to be run every 10 seconds
sched.add_cron_job(job_function, second='*/10')
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named apscheduler.scheduler

Comment: @Hudec [You have to install the package with the link Cédric gave you](http://weknowmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/you-must-be-new-here-willy-wonka.jpg)

Comment: @Hudec : Follow the instructions there : http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/index.html#installing-apscheduler

Answer (score 1):

There is a plethora of ways to achieve what you want. The simpliest I can think of is:

```
>>> from time import sleep
>>> while True:
...     sleep(10)
...     print 'hello!'
```

**EDIT:** slightly modified version if your script needs to do other stuff too (see comments):

```
>>> from time import time
>>> counter = time()
>>> while True:
...     if time() - counter > 10:
...         counter = time()
...         print 'hello!'
...     pass  #do other stuff here
```

Comment: this is the simple path, working for most cases, I suspect the problem with this path is 1. being not very accurate if seconds precision is important for you 2. being blocking, the script doesn't do anything else while waiting

Comment: @alonisser - 1: agreed 2: the way I understand the question is not "how to perform a particular action within a more complex script" but "how to run the script"... yet, the observation is true: is a blocking mechanism for the scheduler.

Comment: nice hack! :) as a python imtermediate (well I'm not a newbie anymore..) I think most of a time the python way is keeping it simple and using the python library